# Finding href by anchor text inside table/list

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, beautifulsoup

I'm trying use Python bs4 to extract a href with a specific anchor text from a website into which I successfully logged in (using requests) before.

Here is the pseudo HTML of the landing page:

```
<table class="submissions">
   <thead>some thead</thead>
   <tbody><tr class="active">
           <th scope="row">uninterestingtext</th> 
           <td>uninterestingtext</td><td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="active">
           <th scope="row">uninteresting</th>   
           <td>uninteresting text</td><td></td></tr>
          <tr class="lastrow active"><th scope="row">uninteresting</th>
           <td>uninteresting text</td>
           <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="lastrow inactive">
           <th scope="row">uninteresting text</th>
           <td>uninterestingtext
              <ul>
                <li><a href="uninteresting_href">someLink</a> </li>
                <li><a href="uninteresting_href">someLink</a> </li>
                <li><a href=**InterestingLink**>**Upload...**</a></li>
              </ul>
           </td>
          </tr></tbody></table>
```

Now I am trying to extract the **InterestingLink** by looking for the **Upload...** text between 'a' tags.

Here is what I tried:

```
landing_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(*responseFromSuccessfulLogin*.text, 'html.parser') 
important_page = landing_page_soup.find('a',{'href':True,'text':'Upload...'}).get('href')
```

But this always throws the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

because "important_page" is always "None".

Note: I have made sure, that "*responseFromSuccessfulLogin*.text" is the correct HTML, which contains the desired links.

After reading other forum threads about similar problems I modified the line to use the method 'select' to query for css-selectors as well as the method 'findAll' with no success.

I feel like I'm messing up, because it's a table, the links are inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup accept callable objects.

```
html = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
important_page = html.findAll('a', href=True, text=lambda i: i if 'Upload...' in i else False)

print(important_page[0]['href'])
```

Comment: Hey @Lara Maia, thanks for the quick reply! I could not get the lambda construct working for me, however 'code' important_page = html.find('a', text='Upload...')['href'] 'code' is now working fine now :) I must have been wrong with the 'href=True'. Greets!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

This:

```
important_page = landing_page_soup.find('a', title='Upload...')['href']
```

works perfectly for me. I get only the link I want.